# Filtering eloquent collection with array column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to filter eloquent model by a column with is an array. I want to the whole model where that particular column contains a certain element in it (in the array).

I have tried using this :-

```
$admins = User::where('role', ['admin'])->paginate(15);
```

The role is the column which is an array and I want to filter the whole collection where that array column contains the string element of 'admin' but this returns an empty collection.
[image]

Comment: $admins = User::where('role', '=', 'admin')->paginate(15);

Comment: that does not work, returns an empty collection

Comment: Could you paste the database row as eg.?

Comment: Might need a get() on the end of it, like   `User::where('role', '=', 'admin')->get();`

Comment: Added a screenshot of the database row, and also tried adding ->get() behind but I'm getting error "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist."

Comment: The role column is not an array, but seems like a plain string `[admin]`. How do you save it into the database in the first place?

Comment: Ohhh I see... I create that column using "$table->text('role');" cuz I did some researched and laravel doesn't have an array method. And this row of data I used a seeder to seed it into the database. How should I change my code now if I may ask?

Comment: I think I have fixed my column, by adding cast method in my User(Model) defining 'role' as an array. Is my table row still wrong? I have updated the picture attached to this question above. I have tried filtering the eloquent collection with "User::where('role', '=', 'admin')->get();" but still getting "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you are trying to have a role/permission system for your users.

#### Recommended solution

I kindly suggest you to use an external package like [spatie/laravel-permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) or [JosephSilber/bouncer](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer) that integrates nicely with laravel.

#### If you want to implement that anyways by yourself

However, Laravel (or I would better say MySQL/PostgreSQL) support json field type, that might achieve something like what you are looking for. The part I'm not sure about is to look for a value inside the array.

You can see all the available JSON field wheres in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses).

Anyways, if you want to implement that yourself without the limited JSON support I would restructure the database to have these tables:

> **users** (all the fields you have, except for role and permissions)
>   **user_role** (id, user_id, role_id)
>   **roles** (id, name, display_name)
>   **user_permission** (id, user_id, permission_id)
>   **permissions** (id, name, display_name)

With that database you just have to set up the correct relationships for the User, Role and Permission models.

That last method is the way these packages more or less handles their stuff (roles/permissions) internally, and it's definitly a better approach to JSON columns in your users table.

Comment: Ohhh I understand now, I shall try and change my current structure ! Thanks for taking your time to come up with a solution ! :D

Comment: You can always browse the code of these two packages I linked to you and see how they handle the various parts of the ACL system and how they integrates it with the framework.  Anyways, if that solved your issue, you can mark the answer as correct.